# How to rotate a (vertical) clip for multicam in Final Cut Pro X

Tags: multi-camera, fcpx

I have two clips taken at the same time: one taken from a camera, one taken from an iPhone. I am going to switch between the clips to change angles, so I need to create a "New Multicam Clip" in Final Cut Pro X which I use for editing.

My problem is, that the clip from an iPhone for some reason is taken vertically, so I need to rotate it by 90 degrees. While it is easy to rotate a single clip back once it is on a storyline, there seems to be no option either to rotate the clip when it is in the library nor after it was combined into a multicam clip. What I get is a combination of a horizontal footage from a camera and a vertical footage from an iPhone.

How can I:
a) either rotate the clip when it is still located in the library, so it will be horizontal when multicam clip is being created?
b) or rotate by 90 degrees only one clip (angle) of a multicam clip?

Answer (score 0):

Paste the clip into the timeline, do the rotation and render it with a lossless codec. This will take much more space on the harddisk for the raw material, but will be an easy way to have both videos in the same format. If necessary, check for other format corrections to match both videos.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this without having to transcode your footage. Create the multicam clip with both videos as-is, then double-click the multicam clip to get to the multicam editor where you can select each clip individually and make changes to their rotation etc, individually. I've put together a quick screen capture of the steps here: